# Check existence with EXISTS outperform COUNT! ... Not?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I've often read when one had to check existence of a row should **always** be done with EXISTS instead of with a COUNT.

Yet in several recent scenarios I've measured a performance improvement when using count.

The pattern goes like this:

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        someID
        , COUNT(*)
    FROM someTable
    GROUP BY someID
) AS Alias ON (
    Alias.someID = mainTable.ID
)
```

I'm not familiar with methods to tell what's happening "inside" SQL Server so I was wondering if there was a unheralded flaw with EXISTS that gave perfectly sense to the measurements I've done (could EXISTS be RBAR?!).

Do you have some explanation to that phenomena?

EDIT:

Here's a full script you can run:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET STATISTICS IO OFF

DECLARE @tmp1 TABLE (
    ID INT UNIQUE
)


DECLARE @tmp2 TABLE (
    ID INT
    , X INT IDENTITY
    , UNIQUE (ID, X)
)

; WITH T(n) AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS S
) 
, tally(n) AS (
    SELECT
        T2.n * 100 + T1.n
    FROM T AS T1
    CROSS JOIN T AS T2
    WHERE T1.n <= 100
    AND T2.n <= 100
)
INSERT @tmp1
SELECT n
FROM tally AS T1
WHERE n < 10000


; WITH T(n) AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS S
) 
, tally(n) AS (
    SELECT
        T2.n * 100 + T1.n
    FROM T AS T1
    CROSS JOIN T AS T2
    WHERE T1.n <= 100
    AND T2.n <= 100
)
INSERT @tmp2
SELECT T1.n
FROM tally AS T1
CROSS JOIN T AS T2
WHERE T1.n < 10000
AND T1.n % 3 <> 0
AND T2.n < 1 + T1.n % 15

PRINT '
COUNT Version:
'

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'

SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON

SELECT
    T1.ID
    , CASE WHEN n > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS DoesExist
FROM @tmp1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        T2.ID
        , COUNT(*) AS n
    FROM @tmp2 AS T2
    GROUP BY T2.ID
) AS T2 ON (
    T2.ID = T1.ID
)
WHERE T1.ID BETWEEN 5000 AND 7000
OPTION (RECOMPILE) -- Required since table are filled within the same scope

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF

PRINT '

EXISTS Version:'

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'

SET STATISTICS TIME ON

SELECT
    T1.ID
    , CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM @tmp2 AS T2
        WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS DoesExist
FROM @tmp1 AS T1
WHERE T1.ID BETWEEN 5000 AND 7000
OPTION (RECOMPILE) -- Required since table are filled within the same scope

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
```

On SQL Server 2008R2 (Seven 64bits) I get this result

`COUNT` Version:

> Table '#455F344D'. Scan count 1, logical reads 8, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>   Table '#492FC531'. Scan count 1, logical reads 30, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:
>      CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 81 ms.

`EXISTS` Version:

> Table '#492FC531'. Scan count 1, logical reads 96, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>   Table '#455F344D'. Scan count 1, logical reads 8, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:
>      CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 76 ms.

Answer (score 47):

> *I've often read when one had to check existence of a row should **always** be done with EXISTS instead of with a COUNT.*

It's very rare for anything to **always** be true, especially when it comes to databases. There are any number of ways to express the same semantic in SQL. If there is a useful rule of thumb, it might be to write queries using the most natural syntax available (and, yes, that is subjective) and only consider rewrites if the query plan or performance you get is unacceptable.

For what it's worth, my own take on the issue is that existence queries are most naturally expressed using `EXISTS`. It has also been my experience that `EXISTS` [tends to optimize better](https://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) than the `OUTER JOIN` reject `NULL` alternative. Using `COUNT(*)` and filtering on `=0` is another alternative, that happens to have some support in the SQL Server query optimizer, but I have personally found this to be unreliable in more complex queries. In any case, `EXISTS` just seems much more natural (to me) than either of those alternatives.

> *I was wondering if there was a unheralded flaw with EXISTS that gave perfectly sense to the measurements I've done*

Your particular example is interesting, because it highlights the way the optimizer deals with subqueries in `CASE` expressions (and `EXISTS` tests in particular).

#### Subqueries in CASE expressions

Consider the following (perfectly legal) query:

```
DECLARE @Base AS TABLE (a integer NULL);
DECLARE @When AS TABLE (b integer NULL);
DECLARE @Then AS TABLE (c integer NULL);
DECLARE @Else AS TABLE (d integer NULL);

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (SELECT W.b FROM @When AS W) = 1
            THEN (SELECT T.c FROM @Then AS T)
        ELSE (SELECT E.d FROM @Else AS E)
    END
FROM @Base AS B;
```

The [semantics of `CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) are that `WHEN/ELSE` clauses are [generally](https://web.archive.org/web/20140912144142/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/691535/aggregates-dont-follow-the-semantics-of-case) evaluated in textual order. In the query above, it would be incorrect for SQL Server to return an error if the `ELSE` subquery returned more than one row, if the `WHEN` clause was satisfied. To respect these semantics, the optimizer produces a plan that uses pass-through predicates:

[image: Pass-through predicates]

The inner side of the nested loop joins are only evaluated when the pass-through predicate returns false. The overall effect is that `CASE` expressions are tested in order, and subqueries are only evaluated if no previous expression was satisfied.

#### CASE expressions with an EXISTS subquery

Where a `CASE` subquery uses `EXISTS`, the logical existence test is implemented as a semi-join, but rows that would normally be rejected by the semi-join have to be retained in case a later clause needs them. Rows flowing through this special kind of semi-join acquire a flag to indicate if the semi-join found a match or not. This flag is known as the *probe column*.

The details of the implementation is that the logical subquery is replaced by a correlated join ('apply') with a probe column. The work is performed by a simplification rule in the query optimizer called `RemoveSubqInPrj` (remove subquery in projection). We can see the details using trace flag 8606:

```
SELECT
    T1.ID,
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT 1
            FROM #T2 AS T2
            WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID
        ) THEN 1 
    ELSE 0
    END AS DoesExist
FROM #T1 AS T1
WHERE T1.ID BETWEEN 5000 AND 7000
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 3604, QUERYTRACEON 8606);
```

Part of the input tree showing the `EXISTS` test is shown below:

```
ScaOp_Exists 
    LogOp_Project
        LogOp_Select
            LogOp_Get TBL: #T2
            ScaOp_Comp x_cmpEq
                ScaOp_Identifier [T2].ID
                ScaOp_Identifier [T1].ID
```

This is transformed by `RemoveSubqInPrj` to a structure headed by:

```
LogOp_Apply (x_jtLeftSemi probe PROBE:COL: Expr1008)
```

This is the left semi-join apply with probe described previously. This initial transformation is the only one available in SQL Server query optimizers to date, and compilation will simply fail if this transformation is disabled.

One of the possible execution plan shapes for this query is a direct implementation of that logical structure:

[image: NLJ Semi Join with Probe]

The final Compute Scalar evaluates the result of the `CASE` expression using the probe column value:

[image: Compute Scalar expression]

The basic shape of the plan tree is preserved when the optimizer considers other physical join types for the semi join. Only merge join supports a probe column, so a hash semi join, though logically possible, is not considered:

[image: Merge with probe column]

Notice the merge outputs an expression labelled `Expr1008` (that the name is the same as before is a coincidence) though no definition for it appears on any operator in the plan. This is just the probe column again. As before, the final Compute Scalar uses this probe value to evaluate the `CASE`.

The problem is that the optimizer doesn't fully explore alternatives that only become worthwhile with merge (or hash) semi join. In the nested loops plan, there is no advantage to checking if rows in `T2` match the range on every iteration. With a merge or hash plan, this could be a useful optimization.

If we add a matching `BETWEEN` predicate to `T2` in the query, all that happens is that this check is performed for each row as a residual on the merge semi join (tough to spot in the execution plan, but it is there):

```
SELECT
    T1.ID,
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT 1
            FROM #T2 AS T2
            WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID
            AND T2.ID BETWEEN 5000 AND 7000 -- New
        ) THEN 1 
    ELSE 0
    END AS DoesExist
FROM #T1 AS T1
WHERE T1.ID BETWEEN 5000 AND 7000;
```

[image: Residual predicate]

We would hope that the `BETWEEN` predicate would instead be pushed down to `T2` resulting in a seek. Normally, the optimizer would consider doing this (even without the extra predicate in the query). It recognizes *implied predicates* (`BETWEEN` on `T1` and the join predicate between `T1` and `T2` together imply the `BETWEEN` on `T2`) without them being present in the original query text. Unfortunately, the apply-probe pattern means this is not explored.

There are ways to write the query to produce seeks on both inputs to a merge semi join. One way involves writing the query in quite an unnatural way (defeating the reason I generally prefer `EXISTS`):

```
WITH T2 AS
(
    SELECT TOP (9223372036854775807) 
        T2.* 
    FROM #T2 AS T2 
    WHERE T2.ID BETWEEN 5000 AND 7000
)
SELECT 
    T1.ID, 
    DoesExist = 
        CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS 
            (
                SELECT 
                    T2.* 
                FROM T2 
                WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID
            ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM #T1 AS T1
WHERE T1.ID BETWEEN 5000 AND 7000;
```

[image: TOP trick plan]

I wouldn't be happy writing that query in a production environment, it's just to demonstrate that the desired plan shape is possible. If the real query you need to write uses `CASE` in this particular way, and performance suffers by there not being a seek on the probe side of a merge semi-join, you might consider writing the query using different syntax that produces the right results and a more efficient execution plan.

Answer (score 6):

The ["COUNT(*) vs EXISTS" argument](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2007/12/15/exists-vs-count-the-battle-never-ends.aspx) is to do with checking whether a record exists. For example:

```
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE ID=@ID)>0
```

vs

```
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE ID=@ID)
```

Your SQL script isn't using `COUNT(*)` as a record exist check, and therefore I wouldn't say that its applicable in your scenario.

Comment: Any though/conclusion based on the script I posted?